# How can I install iBroadcast Media Sync Lite?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, compiling

*Background*
My computer had a major error and would not allow me to recover/reinstall Windows so I gave up and installed Ubuntu 16 to have a working computer.

I have some understanding of Linux but I do not consider myself proficient enough.

I need a step by step guide for installing a program, iBroadcast Media Sync Lite, that I want to use on my computer. But using other guides have been completely unclear or I have failed completely.

The program I am trying to install is here:
https://github.com/iBroadcastMediaServices/MediaSyncLiteLinux

I have tried to install this, but as far as I know it has failed.

I would appreciate any assistance available.

Comment: The question is unclear. Which parts are unclear? What failed exactly? What were the errors?

Comment: I've posted an answer that I believe will work for you (and for other people trying to install this program). Even if it does, though, I think it would be helpful for you to **[edit]** your question to give full details about how you attempted to install it and exactly what happened. Also, if you believe the problem your computer had that prevented you from using Windows may be relevant to installing this software, please explain. (If not, then it's not really relevant and can probably be removed from your question. If you want *help* with the Windows problem, you could ask about it at [su].)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These instructions are *roughly* based on [the official readme](https://github.com/iBroadcastMediaServices/MediaSyncLiteLinux/blob/master/README.md), but with specific details and an additional step (step III) that I found was necessary to build successfully. I've tested them on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

#### I. Install prerequisites.

First install Git (to download the software), the tools to build the software, and the libraries used by the software:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git build-essential libgtk-3-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev openssl libssl-dev libjansson-dev
```

Choose a place to build the software. The traditional place is `/usr/local/src`, which you can allow administrators (members of the `sudo` group) to read and write files in:

```bash
sudo chgrp sudo /usr/local/src
sudo chmod g+sw /usr/local/src
```

If you're building it somewhere else then you can adjust the following commands accordingly.

#### II. Download the source code.

```bash
cd /usr/local/src
git clone https://github.com/iBroadcastMediaServices/MediaSyncLiteLinux.git
```

Now you have a `MediaSyncLiteLinux` directory that contains the source code. The source code includes two files called `Makefile`, one in the top-level directory and the other in `src`. (Actually there are more than just those two, but those are the ones we care about.)

#### III. Patch the source code to link against libcrypto instead of libssl.

Currently, to build iBroadcast Media Sync Lite in Ubuntu 16.04, it is necessary to modify the `Makefile` in `src`. This is because it links against [libssl](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Libssl_API) but needs [libcrypto](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Libcrypto_API) instead. Future versions of the software (which you, or future readers, would obtain automatically by running the `git` command above) may not require this.

If you skip this step, currently you would get this error during the subsequent `make` step (step IV). The error message will look slightly different if you're using the 32-bit version of Ubuntu.

```
/usr/bin/ld: tools.o: undefined reference to symbol 'MD5@@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

That message [means you must link against libcrypto](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=802235).

Go to the `src` subdirectory of `MediaSyncLiteLinux`, back up the file, and open the file in a text editor. These instructions use the [`nano`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/nano.1.html) editor, but you can use whatever text editor you like. (Not a word processor though--the files must remain plain text.)

```bash
cd MediaSyncLiteLinux/src
cp Makefile Makefile.orig
nano -w Makefile
```

In the text editor, find the line that says:

```
LDFLAGS = `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 libcurl libssl` -ljansson -lpthread -rdynamic
```

Change `libssl` to `libcrypto`, so now it says:

```
LDFLAGS = `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 libcurl libcrypto` -ljansson -lpthread -rdynamic
```

Future versions of the software may have this line differ in other ways. You should only make this specific change to it. For example, if there are other libraries listed, don't remove them.

<sup>Everything in OpenSSL that this program needs seems to be provided by `libcrypto`, but in theory a future version might need `libssl` too. If so, you should see error messages about this when you try to build it--probably mentioning `libssl.so`, much as the error message shown above mentioned `libcrypto.so`. Other newly required libraries may be indicated similarly (if you're lucky).</sup>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> exits `nano`, and you will be prompted to save.

#### IV. Build and install the software.

Go to the top-level `MediaSyncLiteLinux` directory that was created by `git clone`. After following step III above, `cd ..` will achieve this (because you were in `MediaSyncLiteLinux/src`). Or you can run:

```bash
cd /usr/local/src/MediaSyncLiteLinux
```

Now to build it just run:

```bash
make
```

<sup>You're running `make` in the directory that contains the *top-level* `Makefile`. This is not the one you edited, though that one will automatically get used during the build too.</sup>

You will see warnings like `warning: ‘gtk_widget_override_color’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]`. That is okay. If there are *errors*, then that will have to be investigated. If not, then you can proceed to install it:

```bash
sudo make install
```

This will install iBroadcast Media Sync Lite in `/usr/local`.

Note that, while I suggest you install it, *installation is actually optional.* As [the readme](https://github.com/iBroadcastMediaServices/MediaSyncLiteLinux/blob/master/README.md) says, you have the option of just always running the `mediasynclite` executable that was created in the top-level `MediaSyncLiteLinux` directory when you ran `make`.

#### V. Run it and see if it works.

The `mediasynclite` command was installed to `/usr/local/bin`. Since that directory is part of users' [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) by default, you can now run that command (from anywhere).

```bash
mediasynclite
```

You should probably run it from the directory where you keep your music. When you run it you'll have to log in to your iBroadcast account. This is what it looks like (after the initial splash screen) when I run it:

[image: Screenshot of MediaSync Lite login dialog box prompting for email address and password to log in to the iBroadcast service.]

If you chose not to run `sudo make install` and want to run the compiled executable (from anywhere), you can run:

```bash
/usr/local/src/MediaSyncLiteLinux/mediasynclite
```

#### VI. Finding the Installed Files

You may someday want or need to find the files that were installed. When you run `sudo make install` it will tell you what files are being created. You may want to save that information.

*As of the current version*, they are:

- The single binary executable file `/usr/local/bin/mediasynclite`.
- The `/usr/local/share/mediasynclite` directory and its contents.

I mention this mainly because, as of now, uninstalling with `sudo make uninstall` is not supported. You can remove the files manually to uninstall. If you like, you could also [use `checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) instead of the `sudo make install` command given above, to make uninstallation easier. Or you can use it without installing it, by running the `mediasynclite` command in the top-level source directory.

#### *Further Reading*

Though it doesn't really tell you enough specific information to build this particular program if you don't have any experience compiling software from source code, [**CompilingEasyHowTo**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo) is a useful resource and may interest you.

Comment: I appreciate the effort made to help me try to install this program, however, I am still too new to Linux to understand precisely what I am doing.    My main purpose for doing this is to provide a secondary cloud back up to my music library via this service.  To be honest, all i want is the Deb package and I'd be happy as I have tried to go through these steps but it honestly feels like I'm reading a foreign language trying to understand the commands.

Comment: I took the time and effort to go through the above steps, slowly and it eventually worked and I managed to have the program made and running.  This did work, I'm just not sure where the program went after i completed the login.  This is the next part I need to figure out.

Comment: @Bellepheron I didn't find a .deb--I don't think it's packaged. If you ran the `sudo make install` step there should be a `mediasynclite` executable in `/usr/local/bin`. Either way, there should be an `mediasynclite` executable in the `MediaSyncLiteLinux` directory that contains the source code (though if you did run the `sudo make install` step, I suggest using the installed executable). Did you install it but get `mediasynclite: command not found` when you run `mediasynclite`? If so, what do `echo "$PATH"`, `file /usr/local/bin/mediasynclite` and `ls -l /usr/local/bin/mediasynclite` show?

Answer (score -1):

Open any terminal

Run below commands

```
git clone https://github.com/iBroadcastMediaServices/MediaSyncLiteLinux
cd MediaSyncLiteLinux
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort in trying to help.  I tried this method and it did not work.